# How is upcasted object stored in Heap in Java

Tags: java, jvm

So I wrote a simple java code here as shown below.

```
package com.example.aakash;

public abstract class Book {
    String title;
    String author;

    Book(String t,String a){
        title=t;
        author=a;
    }

    abstract void display();
}
```

So Book is an abstract class which is to be extended by two different class called MyBook and ABook class as shown below.

```
package com.example.aakash;

public class MyBook extends Book {
    private int price;

    MyBook(String t, String a,int p) {
        super(t, a);
        price = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(){ 
        System.out.println("Title: "+title); 
        System.out.println("Author: "+author); 
        System.out.println("Price: "+price); 
    }
}

package com.example.aakash;

public class ABook extends Book {
    private int price;

    ABook(String t, String a,int p) {
        super(t, a);
        price = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(){ 
        System.out.println("Title: "+title); 
        System.out.println("Author: "+author); 
        System.out.println("Price: "+price); 
    }
}

package com.example.aakash;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Book> myArray = new ArrayList<Book>();
        String bookName = "Book";

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                String tempBook = bookName + i;
                String author = "Author2";
                Book temp  = new MyBook(tempBook,author,i*50);
                myArray.add(temp);
            }else{
                String tempBook = bookName + i;
                String author = "Author1";
                Book temp  = new ABook(tempBook,author,i*50);
                myArray.add(temp);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            Book temp  = myArray.get(i);
            temp.display();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        }
        myArray.get(5).display();
    }
}
```

Okay so when I run this program, the display method print the right book,author and price every single time. Just the way they are stored. However at runtime, JVM doesn't know that weather a Book object on the array list is of type MyBook or ABook. So my question is how does calling the display method print the right book every single time. How does ArrayList of Book object get stored on heap? (i.e all objects get store in heap in Java) Does it store it as upcasted Book object. Or does it store it as the actual MyBook and ABook type of object so that when display method is called, JVM explicitly knows that weather the method on MyBook or ABook is to be called?

P.S. Yes example is kind of bad but suppose I don't even have similar display method on MyBook and ABook. Even then the JVM still executes the correct display method. So please explain what is going on in JVM when up-casting is done.

Comment: Which method is getting called for which class is defined at compile time.

Comment: `However at runtime, JVM doesn't know that weather a Book object on the array list is of type MyBook or ABook.` It knows.

Comment: @KevinEsche So in heap it will get stored as Book object right?

Comment: @YoungHobbit is it because of the fact that at compile time it determines the method to be called? So it knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete object is an `ABook` declared as `Book`.

Which `display` method select is resolved *at runtime*, not a compile time.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If the method that is to be invoked is an **instance method**, the actual
>   method to be invoked will be determined at **run time**, using dynamic
>   method lookup (§15.12.4).

Basically it means that the real instance type is taken at runtime. If the method is overwritten in that class this method is executed, if it is not overwritten the method of the super class is invoked.

Comment: So in array list there is just pointer to that object right? And object is not casted at all and is stored as of type MyBook on heap?

Comment: Basically yes, in java is called reference, but it is exactly the same

Comment: @StackPointer: The object *is* casted, but casting doesn’t change the object, but just the type of the reference. The type of an object never changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up objects and references. You never store an object in an `ArrayList`, you are just storing a *reference* to an object. A reference might have a broader type than the object it is pointing to, but that never changes the actual type of the object.

In fact, due to *type erasure*, an `ArrayList<Book>` doesn’t even contain references of the type `Book`, it has no knowledge about it. It only contains references of type `Object`, but that’s sufficient for the `ArrayList` to work as all it needs, is the method `boolean equals(Object)` that is declared in `java.lang.Object`. Since the type of the reference does not change the type of the actual object, invoking `equals` on an object via a reference typed as `Object` will still invoke the most specific method of the actual type, if the `equals` method has been overridden.

You may also store the same object multiple times in a `List`, whereas “store an object” is a colloquial term which you *always* have to translate to “store a reference to that object” for yourself. There’s still only one object if you do that and the list will just contain multiple references to it. Modifying that object through one of these references will become visible through all other references immediately.

The type of an object is fixed right when it is created and stored within the object in an implementation specific manner. That’s also the reason why a runtime type cast narrowing the type to a more specific one can verify the correctness. The cast is not changing the type of the object, it’s only creating a new reference to the same object with a more specific type out from a reference with a broader type, after the correctness has been proven. This also happens implicitly when retrieving a reference from the `ArrayList<Book>`; the reference of type `Object` stored in the list is converted to the reference of type `Book` you will receive.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called Polymorphism.
ABook is a Book
MyBook is a Book

You can have an ArrayList and have inside objects of ABook and MyBook.
But everytime that you get an object of this ArrayList, you can only call book's method, unless you make a downcast to one of this subclass. But you have to be sure of the subclass before the cast, because you might get an CastException.

Finally, if you call an override method, at runtime he will always call the object method. At runtime he we always call the objects method.